# C# start Child Process (in CMD window) as Administrator with custom environment variables

Tags: c#, winapi, cmd

I have a program which wraps around some Windows SDK executables and opens them in a separate CMD window.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C signtool.exe [args] & pause";
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
```

Right now, I have the Windows SDK folder added to my system's Path environment variable. Is there a way to programmatically add the Windows SDK folder to the Path environment variable of the user OR run the process with the SDK folder added to the Path variable of that particular CMD window?

This is the folder I need added to each CMD window's Path variable:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x86
```

This sub-process must run as administrator. It does not need to receive the output of the child process.

Comment: Add the directory to your C# processes PATH variable and this will be inherited by the child process. Also, it's pointless to use cmd. Start signtool directly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environment

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo) and its [`Environment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environment) property instance to set this up.

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
var defaultPath = startInfo.Environment["PATH"];
var newPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\10.0.16299.0\\x86" + ";" + defaultPath;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/c set > D:\\env.txt";
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
startInfo.Environment["PATH"] = newPath;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // required to use Environment variables
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: I'm having only one problem with this solution - the "runas" part no longer works (it isn't running as Administrator anymore, which I actually do need). Help.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I didn't test thoroughly, but I was rather surprised that it didn't object to using `Verb` without `UseShellExecute`..

Comment: @G.S. If you update the question (title and body) to ask how to start a child process as admin and supply environment variables, I'll delete this answer. In your question, please note that you can only use the Environment and EnvironmentVariables properties with UseShellExecute = false, but that causes it to silently disregard the Verb.

Comment: I've rephrased it. I also discovered what _could_ be a workaround, but I don't know much about PowerShell...

`powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"`

This opens a new CMD window as administrator, but I have no idea how to pass, say, a command with arguments to it. I don't need to get the results of a CMD window I open, thankfully. I just need to open a window and run a command as Administrator.

Comment: Why are you so keen to start cmd? Why don't you run signtool?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It looks like OP is trying to display the result of signtool with a "Press any key to continue..." message (pause). Even if OP just wants to run signtool, the problem still exists. They want to run signtool elevated with a modified environment.

Comment: @MichaelGunter Exactly. I used signtool as an example, but I actually run much, much longer commands that could take several minutes to complete. It isn't my app's business to know how the commands finish - it is just there to generate the commands and run them so I don't manually have to figure out the commands myself.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of hurdles to overcome here.

1. As you've discovered, the `Environment` and `EnvironmentVariables` properties of `ProcessStartInfo` cannot be used when `UseShellExecute` is `true` (an exception is thrown). But `Verb` only works when `UseShellExecute` is `false` (the `Verb` is silently ignored). This comes down to the differences between [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) (the core Win32 function) and [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)/[`ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx) (the shell function).
2. As another commenter suggested, you might try setting the environment in the parent process and then starting the child process. However, [elevated processes don't inherit the environment from a non-elevated parent process](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130703-00/?p=3903).

I would be willing to bet that there is a way to do what you want using a correct series of Win32 calls to get an elevated token and then calling something like [`CreateProcessAsUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx). I am also willing to bet it'll be a little error-prone and ugly in C# because of the necessary struct marshaling. So instead of trying to figure that out for you, I'll offer another suggestion:

Just programmatically write a batch script that sets the environment and invokes `signtool.exe`. You can then invoke that batch script using the `runas` verb as you're currently doing.